# isDigit(char) not working

Tags: java

I'm not able to use isDigit() in my program. When I use it says "The method isDigit(char) is undefined for type calculator". 
*calculator is my class.
*I'm trying to go through all the characters of a string and check whether they are valid input characters for a calculator.

Comment: Add your code to the question

Comment: I'd guess you didn't declare the method `isDigit` in your class, posting some code could lead to more helpful and less speculated answers however.

Comment: If you use an IDE, it can automatically suggest and fix missing static imports.

Comment: thanks guys but solved it already!!

Comment: Could you please answer your own question and tell us how you solved it? That way everyone can benefit from your experience with this problem.

Comment: the answer given below..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) is a static method of the [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class. To call a static method you should prefix the method reference with the name of the class it belongs to, like this:

```
Character.isDigit(ch);
```